# getting error while deleting user on quickblox

Tags: quickblox

How to delete user on quickblox ? I am using javascript sdk.. QB.users.delete(userId,function(err, result){}); I am getting error :- Cannot read property 'external' of undefined

Comment: anybody knows ,what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

A user can delete himself from the platform using sample code below:

```
var userId = 1;
QB.users.delete(userId, function(error, result){

});
```

The error *"Cannot read property 'external' of undefined"* can mean that the provided id does not exist in the back-end.

Comment: i am passing correct userId ,still getting same error ? i am pasing 9 digit (102693803) userId

Comment: Try checking the same with a clear sample from QuickBlox: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/tree/gh-pages/samples/chat

If the same issue occurs, please submit a ticket to QuickBlox support: https://assist.quickblox.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit

Comment: ok ,i got the solution , user need to create session first ,then,login, then at last step delete user only then, user will be successfully deleted :0